# Total numbers represented in a basis of b system, with n digits for the mantissa

Tags: floating-point, numbers, precision, number-formatting

I am trying to prove that in a system of basis b, n digits for the mantissa and e for the exponent ( m <= e <= M) there is a total of: 1 + 2(b-1)(M-m+1)b^{n-1}. When computing it I reach that:

There is a total of (M-m+1) different exponents, b^n different mantissas for each exponent, and multiplying by 2 for negative and positive as well as adding 0, I get: 1 + 2(M-m+1)b^n. What am I thinking about wrong here? Thanks =)

Comment: One of those b^n mantissas is zero, but you have already accounted for zero with the `1 + ...`. Your formula also counts it for every possible exponent, but there's only one zero.

Comment: @rajit_alkmaar, With "n digits for the mantissa", may the most significant digit (msd) be a 0?  Is a msd as 1 implied?  Are sub-normals supported?